# Google checks occur issue in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, checkstyle

I install checkstyle plugin in eclipse, and set google checks as default.

And I make a JUnit class like this.

```
public class TokenTest {

    @Test public void testToken() {
        Token tokenWhite = new Token("WHITE");
        Token tokenBlack = new Token("BLACK");

        assertNotNull("TokenTest-Construct-White", tokenWhite);
        assertNotNull("TokenTest-Construct-Black", tokenBlack);
    }
}
```

There is no javadoc comment in class and method.

I checked it using google check.

But "'method def modifier' have incorrect indentation level 4, expected level should be 2." occurs in column3.
And "'member def type' have incorrect indentation level 8, expected level 
 should be 4.", "'method def' child have incorrect indentation level 8, expected level should be 4." occurs in column4.
Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: Chabge every TAB for 2 spaces, that should make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent your code like this

```
public class TokenTest {

    @Test
    public void testToken() {
        Token tokenWhite = new Token("WHITE");
        Token tokenBlack = new Token("BLACK");

        assertNotNull("TokenTest-Construct-White", tokenWhite);
        assertNotNull("TokenTest-Construct-Black", tokenBlack);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I edited incorrect.
I implement in my code correct like this.


Write @Test annotation in a new line also occur warning.

Comment: 'method def modifier' have incorrect indentation level 4, expected level should be 2.

This warning occurs in "@Test" Line 3.

Comment: check if there are 4 white spaces then remove 2. Your problem will get resolved by doing this. Moreover i think its for public keyword.